# MySql Query : How to Write Inner Select Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have five tables: 1. courses 2.departmetns 3.students 4. enroll_courses 5.results

```
Departments has id
Courses has id, department_id
Students has id,department_id
Enroll_courses has id, courses_id,students_id
Results has id, courses_id,students_id
```

I have to select courses.name which are in enroll_courses tables but not in results table.

I have written the query, I couldn't get the exact answer. If anyone can help me to find the solution.

Query:

```
SELECT courses.name 
FROM courses 
    JOIN departments ON courses.department_id = departments.id 
    JOIN students ON departments.id = students.department_id 
WHERE students.id = 9
  AND courses.id IN (SELECT course_id FROM enroll_courses)
```

Comment: Let us know the design of your tables and we'll be able to help. Edit the original question, don't reply in the comments.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server here? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You state that your Courses table has id, department_id, but you're then referencing courses.name. update it with all fields and we'll have more of a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Its a little bit blind shoot since you didn't provide any `DDL's` , but I assume `results` table have a course_id column , if not, change it to the relation. You can do this with `EXISTS()` and `NOT EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT courses.name 
FROM courses 
    JOIN departments ON courses.department_id = departments.id 
    JOIN students ON departments.id = students.department_id 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM enroll_courses ec WHERE ec.course_id = courses.id)
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM results r WHERE r.course_id = courses.id)
  AND students.id =9
```

Comment: There is a problem with syntax Error in your Query, I couldn't get it. Can you check my updated Qus please?

Comment: I run with your above query earlier and got 3 errors.
3 errors were found during analysis.

`Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 285)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 289)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 295)`

Comment: How are you running this? This query is perfectly fine, and is ANSI SQL, it works on almost every DBMS!

Comment: See the problem was in your query is that in first exist the `)` should  put after second exist `)` , then the query will run, please update the solution and I will accept the answer.

Comment: @RandeepSingh I'm sorry I don't see the problem, the query looks fine to me :S You are welcome to edit my question yourself so I'll see what is the typo( the edit button below the answer)